# Self-built extension module slower than built-in c module

Tags: python, performance, python-c-api

To learn how to create C-extensions I've decided to just copy a built-in `.c`-file (in this case [`itertoolsmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c)) and placed it in my package. I only changed the names inside the module from `itertools` to `mypkg`.

Then I compiled it (Windows 10, MSVC Community 14) as `setuptools.Extension`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

itertools_module = Extension('mypkg.itertoolscopy',
                              sources=['src/itertoolsmodulecopy.c'])

setup(...
      ext_modules=[itertools_module])
```

The default uses the compiler flags `/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD` and I read somewhere that these defaults equals the settings of how the python was compiled. However I use conda (64bit setup) so this might *not necessarily* be true.

It all went well - but a benchmark for `filterfalse` showed that it's almost a factor 2 slower than the built-in:

```
import mypkg
import itertools

import random

a = [random.random() for _ in range(500000)]
func = None

%timeit list(filter(func, a))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.42 ms per loop
%timeit list(itertools.filterfalse(func, a))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.41 ms per loop
%timeit list(mypkg.filterfalse(func, a))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.77 ms per loop
```

However, for smaller iterables the discrepancy also becomes smaller:

```
a = [random.random() for _ in range(500)]  # 1 / 1000 of the elements

%timeit list(filter(func, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.66 µs per loop
%timeit list(itertools.filterfalse(func, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop
%timeit list(mypkg.filterfalse(func, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.4 µs per loop
```

I wasn't able to explain this difference in speed but I have to admit that I'm not too familiar with compiling `C`-code. I'm at a loss what actually makes it slower.

The results are the same on python 2.7 with `ifilter` and `ifilterfalse` and the 2.7 version of the `itertoolsmodule.c` file.

Does anyone knows what makes the code perform worse than the built-ins and how one could speed it up?

Comment: Since I'm trying to reproduce your results, what version of python are you targeting and on what platform (x86 or x86_64)?

Comment: The timings were done on 64bit py35 and 64bit py27 (both conda).

Comment: In python2.7 did you do `list(itertools.ifilterfalse(...))`, there is no `itertools.filterfalse` in python2, and `ifilterfalse` returns an iterator

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yes, as stated in the question "_The results are the same on python 2.7 with ifilter and ifilterfalse and the 2.7 version of the itertoolsmodule.c file._".

Comment: @MSeifert Did you happen to find out anymore about this? I compared the built-in `min` function with a function from an extension module that uses identical code. `731 µs`  for the built-in `min` and  `1.07 ms` for the extension module `min` (for some input iterable). This is quite concerning for me.

Comment: @MSeifert I found a fix. Rebuilding Python (via `make`) as in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#compilation-and-linkage) led to identical (even slightly better) timings for the extension module. Very pleased. My config options were `--enable-optimizations --with-lto`. I wonder if `python setup.py install` uses it's own type of options.

Answer (score 6):

Curious about this problem myself I set out to attempt to reproduce the findings.  Though the OP is on windows, it was slightly easier for me to attempt this on linux.  I did eventually try it on windows but I'll walk you through what I did!

### setup

I made a little test harness, it's a shell script but it makes it easier for someone else to try what I'm trying :D

#### test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail
rm -rf itertoolsmodule.c setup.py venv

PYTHON=3.5
FUNCTION=filterfalse
INIT=PyInit_
#PYTHON=2.7
#FUNCTION=ifilterfalse
#INIT=init

wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/$PYTHON/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c"
sed -i "s/${INIT}itertools/${INIT}_myitertools/" itertoolsmodule.c
sed -i 's/"itertools"/"_myitertools"/' itertoolsmodule.c

cat > setup.py << EOF
from setuptools import setup, Extension
mod = Extension('_myitertools', ['itertoolsmodule.c'])
setup(name='foo', ext_modules=[mod])
EOF

virtualenv venv -ppython"$PYTHON"
venv/bin/pip install . -v

cat > test.py << EOF
import _myitertools
import itertools
import random
import time


a = [random.random() for _ in range(500000)]
iterations = range(10)
seconds = 5


def builtins_filter():
    for _ in iterations:
        list(filter(None, a))

_itertools_filterfalse = itertools.$FUNCTION
def itertools_filterfalse():
    for _ in iterations:
        list(_itertools_filterfalse(None, a))

_myitertools_filterfalse = _myitertools.$FUNCTION
def myitertools_filterfalse():
    for _ in iterations:
        list(_myitertools_filterfalse(None, a))


def runbench(func):
    start = time.time()
    end = start + seconds
    iterations = 0
    while time.time() < end:
        func()
        iterations += 1
    return iterations


for func in (builtins_filter, itertools_filterfalse, myitertools_filterfalse):
    print('*' * 79)
    print(func.__name__)
    print('{} iterations in {} seconds'.format(runbench(func), seconds))
EOF
```

### ubuntu16.04 x86_64 python3.5.2 (stock, apt)

(I cut out the (imo) unimportant parts):

```
$ ./test.sh
+ rm -rf itertoolsmodule.c setup.py venv
+ PYTHON=3.5
+ FUNCTION=filterfalse
+ INIT=PyInit_

...

+ venv/bin/pip install . -v

...

    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/tmp/foo/venv/include/python3.5m -c itertoolsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/itertoolsmodule.o
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/itertoolsmodule.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_myitertools.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

...

+ venv/bin/python test.py
*******************************************************************************
builtins_filter
1401 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
itertools_filterfalse
1977 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
myitertools_filterfalse
1981 iterations in 50 seconds
```

### ubuntu16.04 x86_64 python2.7.12 (stock, apt)

```
+ rm -rf itertoolsmodule.c setup.py venv
+ PYTHON=2.7
+ FUNCTION=ifilterfalse
+ INIT=init

...

+ venv/bin/pip install . -v

...

    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c itertoolsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/itertoolsmodule.o
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/itertoolsmodule.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_myitertools.so

...

+ venv/bin/python test.py
*******************************************************************************
builtins_filter
871 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
itertools_filterfalse
1918 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
myitertools_filterfalse
1863 iterations in 50 seconds
```

### Windows!

For windows, I changed the script slightly so it built virtualenvs using `C:\Python##\python.exe` (Using mysysgit so I have some amount of a unix toolset (bash, etc.)).  Changing things from bin to Scripts (for virtualenv), etc.  I don't have/use conda so these'll just be stock python on windows 10

### windows 10 python 2.7.9 (stock, msi installer)

```
+ rm -rf itertoolsmodule.c setup.py venv
+ PYTHON=2.7
+ FUNCTION=ifilterfalse
+ INIT=init

...

+ venv/Scripts/pip install . -v

...

    C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -Ic:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\foo\venv\PC /Tcitertoolsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\itertoolsmodule.obj
itertoolsmodule.c
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\Libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\foo\venv\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\foo\venv\PCbuild /EXPORT:init_myitertools build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\itertoolsmodule.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\_myitertools.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_myitertools.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_myitertools.pyd.manifest

...

+ venv/Scripts/python test.py
*******************************************************************************
builtins_filter
914 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
itertools_filterfalse
2352 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
myitertools_filterfalse
2266 iterations in 50 seconds
```

### windows 10 python3.5.1 (stock, msi installer)

```
+ rm -rf itertoolsmodule.c setup.py venv
+ PYTHON=3.5
+ FUNCTION=filterfalse
+ INIT=PyInit_

...

+ venv/Scripts/pip install . -v

...

    D:\Programs\VS2015\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python35\include -IC:\Python35\include -ID:\Programs\VS2015\VC\INCLUDE -ID:\Programs\VS2015\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tcitertoolsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\itertoolsmodule.obj
itertoolsmodule.c
    creating C:\Temp\pip-1fnf27jo-build\build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    D:\Programs\VS2015\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python35\Libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\foo\venv\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\foo\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\Programs\VS2015\VC\LIB\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\Programs\VS2015\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__myitertools build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\itertoolsmodule.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\_myitertools.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_myitertools.cp35-win_amd64.lib

...

+ venv/Scripts/python test.py
*******************************************************************************
builtins_filter
658 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
itertools_filterfalse
2601 iterations in 50 seconds
*******************************************************************************
myitertools_filterfalse
2715 iterations in 50 seconds
```

### Conclusion

At the very least, my tests with stock python show that the extension module does not exhibit different performance characteristics.

wellp, I spent a half hour on this and didn't produce a reproduction.  Hopefully this is helpful for the next poor soul who attempts this.  I can only guess that conda is doing some additional optimization and then shipping a pyconfig.h file which lies about the flags used to compile.  Though to be honest, I haven't yet ventured into the conda space so I don't know how their ecosystem works

Comment: One slight comment that might help others reproducing my findings.  My versions of python on windows were too old to handle the source on the 2.7 / 3.5 branches and I had to choose versions of the source before `Py_SETREF` were introduced.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to dig through this. If the issue is not reproducible that would be very good news indeed! My [appveyor tests](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MSeifert04/testpkg/build/1.0.21) seem to indicate that you're right. I also created an 32bit conda environment locally and I can't see any timeit-differences there neither. However it still buggers me why it's slower on my 64bit conda environment.